# Load different pages while leaving certains divs behind

Tags: javascript, php, web

I want to know how some web pages move between different PHP pages without reloading the entire page. Here some divs stays the same. If I use AJAX i cannot share the link of the page, so I need to do this. Thank you.

Comment: what do u mean by "share the link of the page"?

Comment: Basically he needs to store the Ajax parameters on the url using #, and check for them onload() in order to display the correct page.

Comment: not really the # tag. I need to have complete new pages but having a certain parts as it is over those pages. Like facebook having side bars but have complete links to other pages. Not Aja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just load a new page and include the same divs of the page :

```
include 'div1.php';
```

You could use the other answers below and just use ajax but also build a url at the same time so you can navigate back to the same structure of the page.
clicking the link modifies the url, eg:

`document.title = document.title + '?div1=true'`

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

and then just does an ajax call to load a new section. And on first page load, parse the url to check what divs to load.

you could use iframes:

```
<iframe src="/div1.php" id="div1"></iframe>
```

And clicking a link loads new stuff to a specific iframe.

Comment: If I use include 'div1.php' will I be able to retain the that part without reloading in the next page (assuming next page too includes it). And will the expanded collapsible parts will remain as before? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AJAX in order to do that.
BUT if you want to be able to share the link or handle reload ou need to build a navigation system using # and some javascript around it.

There is a lot of example for doing that on the web.

https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tutorial%20build%20ajax%20navigation